# Watching videos with hardware acceleration enabled gives me sound but no image

Tags: mplayer, vdpau

When trying to run mplayer2 with vdpau on a vdpau compatible laptop with Nvidia graphics driver, I only get audio from it.

My Nvidia card *should* be supported as far as I can see, so I wonder if the problem is that I don't have the right packages or configuration:

```
avilella@magneto:~$ vainfo 
libva: VA-API version 0.32.0
libva: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
avilella@magneto:~$ optirun vainfo 
libva: VA-API version 0.32.0
libva: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit

mplayer -vo vdpau -ao alsa file.mkv
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
Error opening/initializing the selected video_out (-vo) device.


lspci -vmk | grep -A 8 -B 2 VGA

Device: 00:02.0
Class:  VGA compatible controller
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
SVendor:    ASUSTeK Computer Inc.
SDevice:    Device 1362
Rev:    18
Driver: i915
Module: i915

--

Device: 01:00.0
Class:  VGA compatible controller
Vendor: nVidia Corporation
Device: GT218 [GeForce 310M]
Rev:    ff
ProgIf: ff
```

I tried following the hybrid-dump instructions, and I get this:

```
avilella@magneto:~/hybrid_graphics/hybrid-windump$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
avilella@magneto:~/hybrid_graphics/hybrid-windump$ make clean && make
\rm -f windump.o windump *~ core
gcc -O2  -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c windump.c -o windump.o
windump.c: In function âcapture_rootâ:
windump.c:56:9: warning: unused variable âallImageâ [-Wunused-variable]
windump.c:42:12: warning: unused variable âdummywinâ [-Wunused-variable]
windump.c:41:9: warning: variable âbwâ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
windump.c:40:17: warning: variable âdheightâ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
windump.c:40:9: warning: variable âdwidthâ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
windump.c:35:10: warning: variable âgot_win_nameâ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
windump.c:33:18: warning: unused variable âiâ [-Wunused-variable]
windump.c:33:9: warning: unused variable âncolorsâ [-Wunused-variable]
windump.c:32:9: warning: unused variable âheader_sizeâ [-Wunused-variable]
windump.c:31:9: warning: variable âwin_name_sizeâ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
windump.c:30:14: warning: unused variable âbuffer_sizeâ [-Wunused-variable]
windump.c:29:13: warning: unused variable âcolorsâ [-Wunused-variable]
windump.c:28:19: warning: unused variable âswaptestâ [-Wunused-variable]
windump.c: In function âmainâ:
windump.c:280:17: warning: unused variable âymouseâ [-Wunused-variable]
windump.c:280:9: warning: unused variable âxmouseâ [-Wunused-variable]
gcc -o windump windump.o  -Wl,-O2 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -lX11 -lXext -lXfixes
avilella@magneto:~/hybrid_graphics/hybrid-windump$ ./windump 
Usage: ./windump source target
where source and target are X11 display names.
Example: ./windump :0.0 :0.1
avilella@magneto:~/hybrid_graphics/hybrid-windump$ optirun glxinfo 
name of display: :0.0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: VirtualGL
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SUN_get_transparent_index, GLX_ARB_create_context
client glx vendor string: VirtualGL
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SUN_get_transparent_index, GLX_ARB_create_context
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_visual_info, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, 
    GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SUN_get_transparent_index, GLX_ARB_create_context
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 310M/PCI/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 290.10
OpenGL shading language version string: 3.30 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_ARB_base_instance, GL_ARB_blend_func_extended, 
    GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_compatibility, 
    GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend, 
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, GL_ARB_fragment_program, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, GL_ARB_fragment_shader, 
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GL_ARB_geometry_shader4, GL_ARB_get_program_binary, 
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, GL_ARB_imaging, 
    GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, GL_ARB_internalformat_query, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment, GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multisample, 
    GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, GL_ARB_occlusion_query2, 
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_ARB_point_sprite, 
    GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, GL_ARB_robustness, GL_ARB_sample_shading, 
    GL_ARB_sampler_objects, GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding, 
    GL_ARB_shader_objects, GL_ARB_shading_language_100, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack, GL_ARB_shading_language_include, 
    GL_ARB_shading_language_packing, GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_sync, 
    GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_ARB_texture_float, GL_ARB_texture_gather, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_ARB_texture_multisample, 
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_query_lod, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui, 
    GL_ARB_texture_storage, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, GL_ARB_timer_query, 
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback2, GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced, 
    GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev, GL_ARB_viewport_array, 
    GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_draw_buffers, GL_ATI_texture_float, 
    GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once, GL_S3_s3tc, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
    GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_bindable_uniform, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, 
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, 
    GL_EXT_Cg_shader, GL_EXT_depth_bounds_test, GL_EXT_direct_state_access, 
    GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, GL_EXT_draw_instanced, GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, 
    GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, 
    GL_EXTX_framebuffer_mixed_formats, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GL_EXT_geometry_shader4, 
    GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, GL_EXT_gpu_shader4, 
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_EXT_packed_float, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_point_parameters, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_rescale_normal, 
    GL_EXT_secondary_color, GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, 
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, 
    GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, GL_EXT_texture3D, 
    GL_EXT_texture_array, GL_EXT_texture_buffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1, GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888, 
    GL_EXT_texture_integer, GL_EXT_texture_lod, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, 
    GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, 
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_EXT_texture_storage, 
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV, 
    GL_EXT_timer_query, GL_EXT_transform_feedback2, GL_EXT_vertex_array, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, GL_EXT_x11_sync_object, 
    GL_EXT_import_sync_object, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, 
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_KTX_buffer_region, GL_NV_alpha_test, 
    GL_NV_blend_minmax, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_complex_primitives, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_copy_depth_to_color, GL_NV_copy_image, 
    GL_NV_depth_buffer_float, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_explicit_multisample, 
    GL_NV_fbo_color_attachments, GL_NV_fence, GL_NV_float_buffer, 
    GL_NV_fog_distance, GL_NV_fragdepth, GL_NV_fragment_program, 
    GL_NV_fragment_program_option, GL_NV_fragment_program2, 
    GL_NV_framebuffer_multisample_coverage, GL_NV_geometry_shader4, 
    GL_NV_gpu_program4, GL_NV_gpu_program4_1, GL_NV_half_float, 
    GL_NV_light_max_exponent, GL_NV_multisample_coverage, 
    GL_NV_multisample_filter_hint, GL_NV_occlusion_query, 
    GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object, 
    GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object2, GL_NV_path_rendering, 
    GL_NV_pixel_data_range, GL_NV_point_sprite, GL_NV_primitive_restart, 
    GL_NV_register_combiners, GL_NV_register_combiners2, 
    GL_NV_shader_buffer_load, GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_barrier, 
    GL_NV_texture_compression_vtc, GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, 
    GL_NV_texture_expand_normal, GL_NV_texture_lod_clamp, 
    GL_NV_texture_multisample, GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_NV_texture_shader, 
    GL_NV_texture_shader2, GL_NV_texture_shader3, GL_NV_transform_feedback, 
    GL_NV_transform_feedback2, GL_NV_vdpau_interop, GL_NV_vertex_array_range, 
    GL_NV_vertex_array_range2, GL_NV_vertex_buffer_unified_memory, 
    GL_NV_vertex_program, GL_NV_vertex_program1_1, GL_NV_vertex_program2, 
    GL_NV_vertex_program2_option, GL_NV_vertex_program3, 
    GL_NVX_conditional_render, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info, GL_OES_depth24, 
    GL_OES_depth32, GL_OES_depth_texture, GL_OES_element_index_uint, 
    GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap, GL_OES_get_program_binary, GL_OES_mapbuffer, 
    GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil, GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8, 
    GL_OES_standard_derivatives, GL_OES_texture_3D, GL_OES_texture_float, 
    GL_OES_texture_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_half_float, 
    GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear, GL_OES_texture_npot, 
    GL_OES_vertex_array_object, GL_OES_vertex_half_float, 
    GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SGIX_depth_texture, 
    GL_SGIX_shadow, GL_SUN_slice_accum

16 GLX Visuals
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x021 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x090 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x091 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x092 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x093 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x094 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x095 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x096 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x097 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x098 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x099 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x09a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x09b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x09c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x09d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x05f 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None

167 GLXFBConfigs:
    visual  x   bf lv rg d st  colorbuffer  sr ax dp st accumbuffer  ms  cav
  id dep cl sp  sz l  ci b ro  r  g  b  a F gb bf th cl  r  g  b  a ns b eat
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x075 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x076 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x077 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x078 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x079 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x07a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x07b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x07c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x07d 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x07e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x07f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x080 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x081 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x082 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x083 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x084 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x085 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x086 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x087 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x088 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x089 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x08a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x08b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x08c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x08d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x08e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x08f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x090 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x091 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x092 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x093 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x094 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x095 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x096 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x097 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x098 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x099 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x09a 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x09b 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x09c 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x09d 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x09e 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x09f 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x0a0 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x0a1 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x0a2 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x0a3 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x0a4 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x0a5 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x0a6 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x0a7 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x0a8 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x0a9 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x0aa 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x0ab 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x0ac 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x0ad 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0ae 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0af 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0b0 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0b1 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0b2 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0b3 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0b4 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0b5 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0b6 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0b7 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0b8 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 None
0x0b9 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x0ba 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x0bb 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x0bc 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x0bd 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x0be 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x0bf 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x0c0 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x0c1 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x0c2 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x0c3 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x0c4 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x0c5 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x0c6 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  2 1 Ncon
0x0c7 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x0c8 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .   8  8  8  8 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  4 1 Ncon
0x0c9 24 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  4 16  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0ca 24 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  4 16  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0cb 24 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0cc 24 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0cd 24 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0ce 24 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0cf 24 tc  0  16  0 r  y .   5  6  5  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0d0 24 tc  0  16  0 r  . .   5  6  5  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0d1 24 tc  0   0  0 r  . .   0  0  0  0 .  .  4 16  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0d2 24 tc  0   0  0 r  . .   0  0  0  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0d3 24 tc  0   0  0 r  . .   0  0  0  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0d4 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .  16 16  0  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0d5 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .  16 16  0  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0d6 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .  16 16  0  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0d7 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .  16 16  0  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0d8 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .  32  0  0  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0d9 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .  32  0  0  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0da 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .  32  0  0  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0db 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .  32  0  0  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0dc 24 tc  0  64  0 r  . .  16 16 16 16 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0dd 24 tc  0  64  0 r  . .  16 16 16 16 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0de 24 tc  0  64  0 r  y .  16 16 16 16 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0df 24 tc  0  64  0 r  y .  16 16 16 16 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0e0 24 tc  0 128  0 r  . .  32 32 32 32 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0e1 24 tc  0 128  0 r  . .  32 32 32 32 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0e2 24 tc  0 128  0 r  y .  32 32 32 32 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0e3 24 tc  0 128  0 r  y .  32 32 32 32 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0e4 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .  16 16  0  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0e5 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .  16 16  0  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0e6 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .  16 16  0  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0e7 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .  16 16  0  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0e8 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .  16 16  0  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0e9 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .  16 16  0  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0ea 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .  16 16  0  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0eb 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .  16 16  0  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0ec 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .  32  0  0  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0ed 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .  32  0  0  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0ee 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .  32  0  0  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0ef 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .  32  0  0  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0f0 32 tc  0  32  0 r  . .  32  0  0  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0f1 24 tc  0  32  0 r  . .  32  0  0  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0f2 32 tc  0  32  0 r  y .  32  0  0  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0f3 24 tc  0  32  0 r  y .  32  0  0  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0f4 24 tc  0  64  0 r  . .  16 16 16 16 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0f5 24 tc  0  64  0 r  . .  16 16 16 16 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0f6 24 tc  0  64  0 r  y .  16 16 16 16 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0f7 24 tc  0  64  0 r  y .  16 16 16 16 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0f8 24 tc  0  64  0 r  . .  16 16 16 16 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0f9 24 tc  0  64  0 r  . .  16 16 16 16 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0fa 24 tc  0  64  0 r  y .  16 16 16 16 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0fb 24 tc  0  64  0 r  y .  16 16 16 16 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0fc 24 tc  0 128  0 r  . .  32 32 32 32 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0fd 24 tc  0 128  0 r  . .  32 32 32 32 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0fe 24 tc  0 128  0 r  y .  32 32 32 32 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x0ff 24 tc  0 128  0 r  y .  32 32 32 32 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x100 24 tc  0 128  0 r  . .  32 32 32 32 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x101 24 tc  0 128  0 r  . .  32 32 32 32 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x102 24 tc  0 128  0 r  y .  32 32 32 32 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x103 24 tc  0 128  0 r  y .  32 32 32 32 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x104 24 tc  0  16  0 r  . .  16  0  0  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x105 24 tc  0  16  0 r  . .  16  0  0  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x106 24 tc  0  16  0 r  y .  16  0  0  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x107 24 tc  0  16  0 r  y .  16  0  0  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x108 24 tc  0  64  0 r  . .  32 32  0  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x109 24 tc  0  64  0 r  . .  32 32  0  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x10a 24 tc  0  64  0 r  y .  32 32  0  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x10b 24 tc  0  64  0 r  y .  32 32  0  0 .  .  4  0  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x10c 24 tc  0  16  0 r  . .  16  0  0  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x10d 24 tc  0  16  0 r  . .  16  0  0  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x10e 24 tc  0  16  0 r  y .  16  0  0  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x10f 24 tc  0  16  0 r  y .  16  0  0  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x110 24 tc  0  16  0 r  . .  16  0  0  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x111 24 tc  0  16  0 r  . .  16  0  0  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x112 24 tc  0  16  0 r  y .  16  0  0  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x113 24 tc  0  16  0 r  y .  16  0  0  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x114 24 tc  0  64  0 r  . .  32 32  0  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x115 24 tc  0  64  0 r  . .  32 32  0  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x116 24 tc  0  64  0 r  y .  32 32  0  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x117 24 tc  0  64  0 r  y .  32 32  0  0 .  .  4 24  0 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x118 24 tc  0  64  0 r  . .  32 32  0  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x119 24 tc  0  64  0 r  . .  32 32  0  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x11a 24 tc  0  64  0 r  y .  32 32  0  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon
0x11b 24 tc  0  64  0 r  y .  32 32  0  0 .  .  4 24  8 16 16 16 16  0 0 Ncon

avilella@magneto:~/hybrid_graphics/hybrid-windump$ DISPLAY=:8 metacity --replace &
[1] 3775
avilella@magneto:~/hybrid_graphics/hybrid-windump$ Window manager error: Unable to open X display :8

[1]+  Exit 1                  DISPLAY=:8 metacity --replace
```

Comment: added more info

Answer (score 4):

According to the information posted on your question you have a hybrid GPU solution that uses Intel + Nvidia at the same time.

To enable your Nvidia card you need to install Bumblebee or disable the Intel card in your BIOS (if possible).

If disabling your Intel card in your computer's BIOS is not an option you have no choice other than use Bumblebee.

If you need information about Bumblebee please have a look at this post, it explains in detail how to enable support to run Ubuntu with both the Intel and the Nvidia card activated

- [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

If you are using Bumblebee already that does not mean that vdpau support is installed, you need to install vdpau support for your card as described here

- [How to enable VDPAU on GStreamer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78936/how-to-enable-vdpau-on-gstreamer/78942#78942)

After you have successfully managed run run bumblebee `vainfo` will still fail because the Intel card will still be the default card.

I have found [a script](https://github.com/harp1n/hybrid-windump) that will switch the card from the Intel to the Nvidia and try to open the media player. The basic instructions to use this are described [here](https://lists.launchpad.net/hybrid-graphics-linux/msg01800.html), remember this is a script from outside sources, no warranties that this will work are given, you can test it yourself.

Here are the instructions taken from the bug report:

> 1. Build hybrid-windump but don't use the included xorg.conf! 
>      https://github.com/harp1n/hybrid-windump (includes borders for entire dumped window) 
>      https://github.com/gebart/hybrid-windump (included better cursor support, but dumped window will cover portion of Intel desktop and can't be moved)
> 2. Start the Bumblebee X server 
>      optirun glxinfo
> 3. Run Compiz (or Metacity) on Nvidia display so the dumped window can be moved around. If you skip this, VDPAU playback will be green. 
>      DISPLAY=:8 compiz --replace &
> 4. Run mplayer2 
>      DISPLAY=:8 mplayer -vo vdpau videofilename &
> 5. Dump window 
>      ./windump :8 :0.0 &
> 6. You now have VDPAU output!
>
> NB: This also works with Ironhide.

Comment: avilella@magneto:~/hybrid_graphics/hybrid-windump$ DISPLAY=:8 compiz --replace &
[1] 2486
avilella@magneto:~/hybrid_graphics/hybrid-windump$ compiz (core) - Fatal: Couldn't open display :8

[1]+  Exit 1                  DISPLAY=:8 compiz --replace

Comment: @avilella can you please add the steps you too and this out to your question? Adding them as a comment is really not the best option since users reading your question might fail to read this.

Comment: Okis, will do that then.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/102508/running-hybrid-dump-for-vdpau-accelerated-video-playing-on-ubuntu-11-10-with-bum just to make sure it's in one single question now.