# hybrid-dump for VDPAU accelerated video playing on Ubuntu 11.10 with bumblebee 3.0?

Tags: 11.10, hybrid-graphics, bumblebee, vdpau

I am trying to run hybrid-dump for VDPAU accelerated video playing on Ubuntu 11.10 with Bumblebee 3.0 installed and running. But following the instructions in the URL below, I can't get mplayer with vdpau to work:

https://askubuntu.com/a/100812/17702

```
avilella@magneto:~/hybrid_graphics/hybrid-windump$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
avilella@magneto:~/hybrid_graphics/hybrid-windump$ make clean && make

optirun true
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current DISPLAY=:8 metacity --replace &
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current DISPLAY=:8 mplayer -vo vdpau file.720p.mkv
#(in the other gnome-terminal tab)
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current ~/hybrid_graphics/hybrid-windump/windump :8 :0
```

Also tried:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current DISPLAY=:8 mplayer -vo vdpau -vc ffh264vdpau file.720p.mkv
```

I don't get any video from it, only audio. I do get video and audio if I remove the vdpau bit, but then windump is not needed:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current DISPLAY=:8 mplayer file.720p.mkv
```

If I try glxspheres, it works well, like this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current DISPLAY=:8 glxspheres
#(in the other gnome-terminal tab)
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current ~/hybrid_graphics/hybrid-windump/windump :8 :0

Polygons in scene: 62464
Visual ID of window: 0x27
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: GeForce 310M/PCI/SSE2
```

Now video playing. Following the instructions below, I got it to work to some extend:

Edit `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` and added:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth    24
        Virtual  1280 720
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Restarted `bumblebeed`:

```
sudo restart bumblebeed
```

In one of the terminals, I call the `mplayer` command:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/lib/nvidia-current/vdpau DISPLAY=:8 optirun mplayer -vo vdpau -ao alsa file.720p.mkv
```

In another terminal, I then call the `compiz` and then `windump` commands:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current DISPLAY=:8  compiz --replace &

~/hybrid-windump/windump :8 :0
```

PROBLEMS: I am struggling with the size of the video window. In a 1366x768 screen, I set up for a 1280x720 video size, but the image is chopped by about 200 pixels on the right hand side, leaving the same size of black `windump` area.

Any ideas?

Comment: Still not able to do this, I saw a new patch has been added to Mesa 8.1. Is this supposed to help me here? http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTA2MzY

Comment: check hardware acceleration http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04/285681#285681

Answer (score 2):

This is how I got `vdpau`:

1. Edited `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` to have

   ```
   Section "Screen"
       Identifier "Screen0"
       DefaultDepth 24
       SubSection "Display"
           Depth    24
           Virtual  1920 1080
       EndSubSection
   EndSection
   ```
2. Run

   ```
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:/usr/lib/nvidia-current/vdpau DISPLAY=:8 optirun mplayer -vo vdpau file.720p.mkv
   ```
3. Run

   ```
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current DISPLAY=:8  compiz --replace &
   ```
4. Downloaded https://github.com/gebart/hybrid-windump, removed `xorg.conf` from it, then compiled (just `make` command).
5. Run `./windump :8 :0`

**Note:** You don't need to edit `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` and change `KeepUnusedXServer` to `true` as we run MPlayer directly with Optirun.

Answer (score 0):

I can see one flaw in your approach to use the X server started by Bumblebee (`:8`). Once the Bumblebee daemon detects that there are no optirun clients, it shuts down the X server. To make the X server stay alive even if `optirun` has exited:

1. Edit `/etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf` and set `KeepUnusedXServer=true`
2. Restart the daemon using `sudo restart bumblebeed` (beware: this will kill any existing `optirun` application)
3. Trigger a start of the X server: `optirun true` (`true` is just a command that immediately returns, it could be anything)
4. Run an application on the secondary X server. The `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` part is necessary if you are using the nvidia driver:

   ```
   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current DISPLAY=:8 metacity --replace &`
   ```
5. Run windump with: `windump :8 :0`

Note: I could not get this to work with xorg-edgers/ppa+nouveau and the nvidia driver using gebarts' fork. With the nvidia driver, I got a lot tearing when running `glxspheres`. If the resolution of the dumped screen does not match the primary display resolution, you need to probably need to add extra modelines to `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia`. For 1920x1080, the lines to be added looks like:

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth    24
        Virtual  1920 1080
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: I followed the instructions but got this error:    DISPLAY=:8 glxspheres &
[1] 2352
avilella@magneto:~$ Polygons in scene: 62464
ERROR (596): Could not obtain RGB visual with requested properties

[1]+  Exit 255                DISPLAY=:8 glxspheres

Comment: Sounds like you've forgotten the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` setting

Comment: I've indeed updated it now to reflrect that change. glxspheres is now running fine with no tearing, but no mplayer video output

Comment: From your question, I cannot see whether you've started `windump` or not after mplayer.

Comment: Yes, I start it in the other gnome-terminal tab.

Comment: Still not able to do this, I saw a new patch has been added to Mesa 8.1. Is this supposed to help me here? http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTA2MzY

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad people like my solution but I'd like to stress that this is only a proof of concept way of doing VDPAU with Optimus.

gebart wrote hybrid-windump in a way that is heavily CPU-bound since everything is copied from "screen" to "screen" in a rather inefficient way.

Yes, you are using VDPAU for decoding, but you are getting none of the CPU-usage savings.

There's also an option to dump single windows by their x window ID.

For keyboard, you need `Option "AutoAddDevices" "true"`.

You can also use hybrid-windump to start a whole VDPAU-ready desktop session using your DE of choice.

If you still want to use this, here's some videos of what the results look like (depending on X config):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVBMLdeRoUU

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxziIAPFIFY

Answer (score -1):

It should be `DISPLAY=:0; metacity --replace &`

Also, optirun says that your display is clearly :0.0, why are you trying to start metacity on display :8? Do you have a program running on display :8 that we can't see in your post? If you do, please provide us that info as well, please?

Comment: I am just following the instructions in the post: http://askubuntu.com/a/100812/17702

Comment: As a matter of fact yes, bumblebee has been there since day one.