# hybrid-dump for VDPAU accelerated video playing on Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, bumblebee, hybrid-graphics, vdpau

Following the instructions posted in

[hybrid-dump for VDPAU accelerated video playing on Ubuntu 11.10 with bumblebee 3.0?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102508/hybrid-dump-for-vdpau-accelerated-video-playing-on-ubuntu-11-10-with-bumblebee-3)

[Watching videos with hardware acceleration enabled gives me sound but no image](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100786/watching-videos-with-hardware-acceleration-enabled-gives-me-sound-but-no-image)

I have managed to successfully compile and run hybrid-windump both from gebart and harp1n. I am using Bumblebee 3.0.1 with x-swat drivers 304.64 under Xubuntu 12.04 with Nvidia GT 525M.

Running

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/nvidia-current/vdpau:/usr/lib/nvidia_current
DISPLAY=:8 optirun mplayer -vo vdpau videofilename
```

In another window

```
DISPLAY=:8 metacity --replace
```

And in yet another window

```
./windump :8 :0.0
```

Regardless if I compile either of the windump sources with or without included xorg.conf (using respectively gcc and make) The result is always the same. The displayed windump screen is entirely black.

Mplayer reports the following

```
MPlayer svn r34540 (Ubuntu), built with gcc-4.6 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing [F2715AEE].mkv.
libavformat version 53.21.0 (external)
Mismatching header version 53.19.0
libavformat file format detected.
[matroska,webm @ 0x7f573df99940]max_analyze_duration reached
[matroska,webm @ 0x7f573df99940]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
[lavf] stream 0: video (h264), -vid 0
[lavf] stream 1: audio (ac3), -aid 0, -alang jpn
[lavf] stream 2: subtitle (ass), -sid 0, -slang eng, gg
VIDEO:  [H264]  704x480  0bpp  23.976 fps    0.0 kbps ( 0.0 kbyte/s)
Clip info:
title: 01
Load subtitles in ./
SUB: Added subtitle file (1): ./[F2715AEE].ass
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 53.35.0 (external)
Mismatching header version 53.32.2
Selected video codec: [ffh264] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg H.264)
==========================================================================
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders
AUDIO: 48000 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 448.0 kbit/29.17% (ratio: 56000->192000)
Selected audio codec: [ffac3] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg AC-3)
==========================================================================
AO: [pulse] 48000Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
Starting playback...
Unsupported PixelFormat 61
Unsupported PixelFormat 53
Unsupported PixelFormat 81
Movie-Aspect is 1.74:1 - prescaling to correct movie aspect.
VO: [vdpau] 704x480 => 834x480 Planar YV12 
A:  22.0 V:  22.0 A-V:  0.000 ct:  0.042   0/  0 11%  1%  0.6% 0 0
```

I get the following image https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0Z4p.png
There seems to be a window inside of that area, although I am unable to move, resize or close it. The same happens when running glxspheres, but the invisible window has different size and takes up the whole black area.

Can anyone help me out with getting the image display correctly?