# Should I install privative Nvidia drivers if I'm using Bumblebee?

Tags: nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, vdpau

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, and I have Bumblebee installed. I've recently realized that "Additional Drivers" has finally detected my Nvidia GeForce GT 630M GPU, and it is asking me to install `vdpau` stuff. I don't know whether it's safe installing it this way. Is it going only to add `vdpau` support, or is the proprietary driver going to be used instead of Bumblebee?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will break your bumblebee set up and you will most likely not be able to boot completely. 
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

vdpau will need to be added by the bumblebee project for it to work with your set up.
There is an answer here with a hack to use vdpau but it is still cpu intensive and is not something you would do in additional drivers and I do not recommend it.
[vdpau](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102508/hybrid-dump-for-vdpau-accelerated-video-playing-on-ubuntu-11-10-with-bumblebee-3)