# VLC Player - Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so

Tags: nvidia, video, vlc, vdpau

I have been struggling to resolve this issue with VLC not using my 1030's hardware decoding with VLC using VDPAU. Hope someone here can help me solve this issue. Same problem for H264 and H265. VLC falls back to CPU rendering just fine, but I need to figure out why it isn't able to load VDPAU hardware decoding for my Nvidia GT 1030.

A bit of info to get started...

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

4.15.0-39-generic
      
nvidia-smi   
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 390.77                 Driver Version: 390.77                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GT 1030     Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 35%   28C    P8    N/A /  30W |    116MiB /  1996MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       943      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            62MiB |
|    0      1090      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          52MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Information string: NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library  390.77  Tue Jul 10 22:09:49 PDT 2018
MPEG1                           0 65536  4096  4096
MPEG2_SIMPLE                    3 65536  4096  4096
MPEG2_MAIN                      3 65536  4096  4096
MPEG4_PART2_SP                  3  8192  2048  2048
MPEG4_PART2_ASP                 5  8192  2048  2048
HEVC_MAIN                      153 262144  8192  8192
HEVC_MAIN_10                   --- not supported ---
HEVC_MAIN_STILL                --- not supported ---
HEVC_MAIN_12                   --- not supported ---
HEVC_MAIN_444                  --- not supported ---

/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.390.77
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.390.77

VLC media player 3.0.4 Vetinari (revision 3.0.4-0-gf615db6)
[000000000210d3b0] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[00007f6c48c06a30] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
```

**Edit:** Question was in regard to getting VDPAU hardware decoding working, not VA-API. Either way, even after following the instructions for VA-API, still cannot get hardware decoding to function properly, whether VLC is set to use VA-API or VDPAU. Errors can be found in comments to OP.

Error logs:

```
VAProfileMPEG2Simple :  VAEntrypointVLD VAProfileMPEG2Main :    VAEntrypointVLD VAProfileMPEG4Simple :  VAEntrypointVLD VAProfileMPEG4AdvancedSimple :  VAEntrypointVLD <unknown profile> : VAEntrypointVLD VAProfileH264Main : VAEntrypointVLD VAProfileH264High : VAEntrypointVLD VAProfileVC1Simple :    VAEntrypointVLD VAProfileVC1Main : VAEntrypointVLD VAProfileVC1Advanced :   VAEntrypointVLD

Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0 libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1 libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)

[00007f55080a34c0] vaapi_drm generic error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0 libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1 libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)

[00007fae100a37a0] vaapi_drm generic error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory [00007fae1cc0c400] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

Comment: Check the output of `vainfo` (installable from `vainfo` package).

Comment: ```libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/nvidia_drv_video.so
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I know if nvidia vdpau is working for mplayer/vlc/totem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45996/how-can-i-know-if-nvidia-vdpau-is-working-for-mplayer-vlc-totem)

Comment: As stated in duplicate question - you should install `vdpau-va-driver` package.

Comment: ```VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG4Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG4AdvancedSimple    : VAEntrypointVLD
      <unknown profile>               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD```

Comment: I switched the hardware decoder setting in VLC to ```VA-API video decoder```
Now I get the following set of errors.

Comment: ```Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)```

Comment: ```[00007f55080a34c0] vaapi_drm generic error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)```

Comment: ```[00007fae100a37a0] vaapi_drm generic error: vaInitialize: unknown libva error
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[00007fae1cc0c400] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread```

Comment: Solved it myself. Issue is with the snap install of VLC player. apt-get install of VLC doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Also, removing the 390.77 nvidia drivers and then installing 415.18 from the ppa fixed an opengl rendering issue. Using strictly VDPAU now, with VA-API removed completely.

Comment: Please don't leave crucial information like errors in the comments.  Comments may be deleted automatically by the system at any time.  Please [edit] your question as it should stand by itself without comments.  **;-)**

Comment: You don't really need to add **Resolved** in title and body since this isn't a *forum*. Also, since you solved your problem on your own and have already written the answer, do mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue in this case was with the snap install of VLC player.

Removing the snap install with:

```
sudo snap remove vlc
```

Following it up with:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge *vlc*
```

Install VLC with apt:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

For another issue I had with openGL rendering of the video output, I removed/purged the 390.77 driver and added the `ppa:graphics-driver` and installed 415.18.

Example of good log history after fix:

```
VLC media player 3.0.4 Vetinari (revision 3.0.4-0-gf615db6332)[000055963f262570] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface. [00007fb868c09430] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library 415.18 Thu Nov 15 21:34:27 CST 2018 for hardware decoding 
[00007fb868cc1d60] avcodec decoder: Using NVIDIA VDPAU Driver Shared Library 415.18 Thu Nov 15 21:34:27 CST 2018 for hardware decoding
```

Comment: If you installed VLC using snap then in my opinion running `sudo apt-get remove --purge *vlc*` is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you don't require the nVidia driver, you can go into VLC settings and select another output in the Video tab.