# cannot play DVDs with ubuntu 18.04

Tags: vlc, dvd

I used to have Ubuntu 16.04 and I always could play DVDs with VLC. However, after an update to 18.04 I cannot do that anymore.

I have already tried the following:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras   
sudo apt install libavcodec-extra    
sudo apt install libdvd-pkg    
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

I have also installed `libdvdread4` and `libdvdnav4` and `libdvdcss2`.

But when after I put the disc in and try to load it in VLC, I see the opening screen of the DVD for a few seconds after which it disappears again.

Can anyone help? thanks!

this is what appears in the terminal:

```
katrien@katrien-ThinkPad-T400:~$ vlc
VLC media player 3.0.4 Vetinari (revision 3.0.4-0-gf615db6332)
[000055c5a5985570] main libvlc: Vlc draait met de standaardinterface. Gebruik 'cvlc' om vlc zonder interface te gebruiken.
[000055c5a59894e0] main playlist: playlist is empty
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 6.0.0
libdvdread: Attempting to use device /dev/sr0 mounted on /media/katrien/NAAR_BUITEN for CSS authentication
libdvdnav: Can't read name block. Probably not a DVD-ROM device.
libdvdnav: vm: dvd_read_name failed
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00400000. Regions: 1 2 3 4 5 6 8

libdvdread: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
libdvdread: This can take a _long_ time, please be patient

libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.VOB at 0x00000134
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_0.VOB at 0x000001ab
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_1.VOB at 0x00000c7e
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_02_0.VOB at 0x001034fd
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_02_1.VOB at 0x0010354a
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Found 2 VTS's
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'nl' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: nl 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'nl' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: nl 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'nl' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: nl 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'nl' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: nl 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'nl' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: nl 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'nl' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: nl 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'nl' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: nl 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'nl' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: nl 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'nl' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: nl 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'nl' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: nl 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'nl' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: nl 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'nl' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: nl 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'nl' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: nl 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'nl' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: nl 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'nl' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: nl 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'nl' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: nl 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'nl' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: nl 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'nl' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: nl 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'nl' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: nl 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'nl' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: nl 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'nl' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: nl 
libva info: VA-API version 1.1.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_1
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
[00007f2c9c06d5f0] vaapi generic error: config doesn't support forced fourcc
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_i965.so: kan gedeeld objectbestand niet openen: Bestand of map bestaat niet
[00007f2c9804a370] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
Drijvendekomma-berekeningsfout (geheugendump gemaakt)
katrien@katrien-ThinkPad-T400:~$ ^C
katrien@katrien-ThinkPad-T400:~$ ^C
katrien@katrien-ThinkPad-T400:~$
```

```
katrien@katrien-ThinkPad-T400:~$ dpkg -l | grep vdpau
ii  libvdpau1:amd64                            1.1.1-3ubuntu1                               amd64        Video Decode and Presentation API for Unix (libraries)
ii  mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64                   19.0.2-1ubuntu1.1~18.04.2                    amd64        Mesa VDPAU video acceleration drivers
ii  vdpau-driver-all:amd64                     1.1.1-3ubuntu1                               amd64        Video Decode and Presentation API for Unix (driver metapackage)
ii  vdpau-va-driver:amd64                      0.7.4-6ubuntu1                               amd64        VDPAU-based backend for VA API
katrien@katrien-ThinkPad-T400:~$ ^C
katrien@katrien-ThinkPad-T400:~$
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am not an expert, so can you please explain me how to  "Start VLC from command line" and "Check the terminal you started it on for error notices"?

Comment: Here it is (some parts are in Dutch but most is in english):

Comment: that is unreadable. Please add it to the question  so it can be formatted ;) and guess what .. there are more dutch people on here than you would expect :D

Comment: done! thans for the tip

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep vdpau` please.

Comment: @nobody : Sorry can you please explain to a non-expert what you need and how I can do that?

Comment: open terminal and type `dpkg -l | grep vdpau` with cp&past, and show the output. edit your question and show it. I want to see which packages related to vdpau on your system are.

Comment: @nobody : clear. done. Interested to hear your feedback

Comment: It's trying to open libvdpau_i965 library to do hardware decoding, but Intel don't provide the library. Apparently you can use va_api, but https://askubuntu.com/a/1097498/29073 indicates that installing with apt instead of snap fixes their issue, maybe it will work for you too. If it works write it up as an answer and post it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt install libvdpau-va-gl1
```

Then change with `sudo nano /etc/X11/Xsession.d/20vdpau-va-gl`

remove  any `#` in  following block

```
[ ! -f /usr/lib/$(arch)-$(uname -s | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')-gnu/vdpau/libvdpau_va_gl.so.1 ] || \
   export VDPAU_DRIVER=va_gl
```

This enables libvdpau-va-gl as the default VDPAU driver.

Reboot.

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/X11/Xsession.d/20vdpau-va-gl
```

remove means delete them.

Comment: thanks! What do you mean by "remove any # in following block"?

Comment: It means if you find any line that begins with this symbol: '#', remove/delete that symbol and keep the rest of line. Because every line that begins with '#' is considered as a comment. So removing the '#' means: un-comment that line. For example you find a line like this: `# bla bla bla bla`, you should remove the '#' so that the line becomes like this `bla bla bla`

Comment: I 've followed the instructions up till sudo apt install libvdpau-va-gl1. After that there seemed to be a problem with my memory (hard disk too full) which a friend of mine solved. The DVD player now works a s well. Thanks for all tips.