# VLC Player - Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so (v2)

Tags: vlc

Fresh install of Ubuntu on an old Intel NUC. The purpose is to play a video on repeat for an installation. I opted for VLC. The video is an mp4.

VLC plays the video perfectly on repeat, but after a couple repeats it gets stuck on the first frame and when launched from a command line, this error is displayed:

Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The answer to the identical question posed here does not work, as apparently you can't install VLC through apt-get anymore: [VLC Player - Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097153/vlc-player-failed-to-open-vdpau-backend-libvdpau-nvidia-so)

Is there another solution, or is there another video player better suited for this task?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GNOME Mplayer: "Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau\_nvidia.so" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13487/gnome-mplayer-failed-to-open-vdpau-backend-libvdpau-nvidia-so-error)

Comment: It did lead me to what seemed to be the solution: go into VLC settings, and in the Video tab set the output to another device. X11 works fine for me. Thanks Jos!

Comment: @colouredmirrorball - if you’ve fixed it, please consider posting the solution as an answer to your question. Thanks!

Comment: @Will Definitely, but this website has a mandatory two day waiting period before it allows you to accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to go into VLC settings, go to Video and then select another output device.